# laravel 5 ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php

I'm creating a laravel website, when I put in the server and start to test the website after a time I get the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`, and I don't know why this happen. Someone know why?

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'], function(){

    Route::get('/', 'Usuario\FuncionarioCtrl@index');
    Route::get('/home', 'Usuario\FuncionarioCtrl@index');

    Route::get('/login/sair', ['as'=>'login.sair', 'uses'=>'Login\LoginCtrl@sair']);

    Route::resource('admin', 'Admin\AdminCtrl');
    Route::resource('ajudas', 'Ajuda\AjudaCtrl');
    Route::resource('brindes', 'Brinde\BrindeCtrl');
    Route::resource('configuracoes', 'Configuracoes\AppCtrl');
    Route::resource('csv', 'Configuracoes\CsvCtrl');
    Route::resource('destinos', 'Destino\DestinoCtrl');
    Route::resource('funcionarios', 'Usuario\FuncionarioCtrl');
    Route::resource('mensagens', 'Mensagem\MensagemCtrl');
    Route::resource('midias', 'Multimidia\multimidiaCtrl');
    Route::resource('noticias', 'Noticia\NoticiaCtrl');
    Route::resource('suportes', 'Suporte\SuporteCtrl');
    Route::resource('regulamentos', 'Regulamento\RegulamentoCtrl');
    Route::resource('retirar', 'Brinde\Retira_brindeCtrl');
    Route::resource('revendas', 'TiposUsuarios\RevendaCtrl');


    Route::resource('vendas', 'TiposUsuarios\VendaCtrl');
    Route::resource('familias', 'TiposUsuarios\FamiliaCtrl');
    Route::resource('outros', 'TiposUsuarios\OutroCtrl');

});

Route::group(['middleware'=>'guest'], function(){
    Route::get('/login', ['as'=>'login.index', 

'uses'=>'Login\LoginCtrl@index']);
        Route::get('/login/entrar', ['as'=>'login.entrar', 'uses'=>'Login\LoginCtrl@entrar']);
});
```

Comment: Are you using nginx or apache. Send me your configuration file so I can help you. It could be that your config file has a 301 redirect somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem. It happens when you load your site on port 443 and you are on port 80.

You probably need to comment out HSTS in your servers config file. Like this.

```
#add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
```